# Maxwell's equations and Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

In a previous question I was told that the Lorentz force can compute the force on charges in one system A from electric and magnetic fields from another system B, but A cannot be the same system as B because then self interaction terms would create infinitely huge energies. (Please let me know if it is possible despite the infinities)

So how is the Lorentz force law used in e.g. network models of a circuit? What parts gets to generate electric/magnetic fields and what parts gets to have charges?

Comment: If you apply the potential of a _point_ particle to itself you get infinite repulsive energy. In a circuit you are dealing with finite charge and current densities. Only if you consider charges and currents to reside on infinitesimally thin plates or wires, or in points, infinities appear.

Comment: But the finite charge is in turn made up of smaller elements, all the way down to point particles in classical theories at least. Say I was simulating each particle, how would it be then.

Comment: Also, not sure how you mean one can avoid the divergences if one speaks of densitites either.

Comment: To create an infinite charge density requires an infinite energy. There is no free lunch. When you describe a circuit, as your question suggests, there is no reason to go there.

Comment: Why not? Do one have bounds on how much error one gets for disregarding self interaction or something? (Which I assume is done in what you describe because you avoid it somehow?)

Comment: Also I just brought up circuits because it is a model to compare to. I want maxwell + lorentz on a circuit, so to speak.

Comment: If you do not use infinite densities self interaction is finite, once more.

Comment: do not know what you mean by infinite densities. Do you mean in norm over the entire space? From what I have gathered there is a 1/r dependence that creates the divergences.